# scala pattern matching on (Try,Try)

Tags: scala

I have the the following Tuple - (t1,t2) :(Try,Try)

I want to check if both succeeded or if one of them failed, but avoid code duplication. Something like:

```
(t1,t2) match {
case (Success(v1),Success(v2)) => new MyClass(v1,v2)
case (Failure(e),_) | (_,Failure(e)) => println(e.getMessage)
}
```

of course the 2nd statement won't work since I need to give different extraction variables. but then I have to check them since I don't know which failed and actually contains Throwable.
I wish Try would act like Future so it'll have Try.sequence(t1,t2).

Any idea how to make this work elegantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a tail recursive call for the `(_, Failure(e))` case:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def apply(t1: Try[Any], t2: Try[Any]): Any =
  (t1, t2) match {
    case (Success(v1), Success(v2)) => new MyClass(v1,v2)
    case (Failure(e), _) => println(e.getMessage)
    case _ => apply(t2, t1)
  }
```

[Cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) lets you do this elegantly. For any `F[_]: Traverse` and `G[_]: Applicative`, it defines the equivalant of `Future.sequence`:

```
def sequence(fa: F[G[A]]): G[F[A]]
```

The library also provides [out of the box instances for Try](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/instances/try.scala). Further reading in the [traverse documentation](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/docs/src/main/tut/typeclasses/traverse.md).

Answer (score 6):

You can convert it to a `Try[MyClass]` like this:

```
val myclass = for {
  v1 <- t1
  v2 <- t2
} yield new MyClass(v1, v2)
```

If `t1` failed, or both `t1` and `t2` failed, `myclass` will be a `Failure` with the `Exception` for `t1`.  If only `t2` failed, `myclass` will be a `Failure` with the `Exception` for `t2`.  Otherwise, `myclass` will be a `Success`.  You can then process it normally using `recover` or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

You can extract a local method:

```
def onFail(e: Throwable) = println(e.getMessage)

(t1,t2) match {
  case (Success(v1),Success(v2)) => new MyClass(v1,v2)
  case (Failure(e),_) => onFail(e)
  case (_,Failure(e)) => onFail(e)
}
```

I'd prefer it to OlivierBlanvillain's first suggestion simply because it's easier to see you can't get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Try, why not using [Scalactic Or and Every](http://www.scalactic.org/user_guide/OrAndEvery)?
So you can write something like this

```
val o1 = Or.from(t1)
val o2 = Or.from(t2)
withGood(o1, o2){(x, y) => {
    //do what you want to do if both are good (or Success in Try)
}}.recover{
    //do what you want to do if either one is bad (or Failure in Try)
}
```

PS: I'm not affiliated with the library.